# can i override singleTableEntityPersister for all my entities?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

to be able to change some property to customType as result of some new annotation i will create i need to be able to extend singleTableEntityPersister for all my entities , is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to be able do that i add to hibernate.properties

hibernate.persister.resolver=MyPersisterClassResolver

and created new MyPersisterClassResolver class as follow:

```
public class MyPersisterClassResolverextends  StandardPersisterClassResolver {
@Override
public Class<? extends EntityPersister> singleTableEntityPersister() {
    return mySingleTabkePersister.class;
```

}
}